# PHP MySQL datagrid that allow to save SQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, datagrid

I'd like to install a PHP program that allow me to show the result and save SQL queries against a DB. Minimum configuration is required. I imaging putting some files in the server and editing a conf.php file with host, user, pass and dbname.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) is what you're looking for.

Comment: No, I'd like something that looks more like a simpler app. Also mysql dont let you save queries.